# Update-TFSWorkspace does not work

Tags: powershell, tfs

Why does

```
Update-TfsWorkspace [[-Item] <QualifiedItemSpec[]>] [-All] [-Force] [-Overwrite] [-Recurse] [-Version <String>]
```

not work?
The equivalent tf.exe works just fine in the exact same folder:

```
tf get itemspec [/version:versionspec] [/all] [/overwrite] [/force] [/preview] [/recursive] [/remap] [/noprompt]
```

Using Win 8.

Here are the exact commands I'm using:

```
Update-TfsWorkspace -Item "$/myfilepaht" this does NOT WORK

tf get itemspec "$/myfilepaht" #this WORKS
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or is the file just not being updated?

Comment: just curious, what is the difference between using `Update-TfsWorkspace -Item "$/myfilepaht"` and using something like `Get-tfschilditem "$/myfilepath" | update-tfsworkspace` ? Haven't used TFS, just googled and saw that everyone piped their input into `update-tfsworkspace`.

Comment: `Update-TfsWorkspace` works just fine for me doing a workspace update.

Comment: I am trying to get a single file. The error it throws with the powershell cmdlet is something to the effect of "Workspace could not be found"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (probably because I have multiple workspaces)
So I solved it with the following code:

```
$tfsCredential = Get-Credential;
$tfsServer = Get-TfsServer -Name "https://tfs.tools4ever.com:443/tfs/t4edevnet2010" -Credential $tfsCredential;;
$tfsws = Get-TfsWorkspace -Server $tfsServer -Computer $hostname -Owner $tfsCredential.UserName;
$tfsPath = $tfsws.GetServerItemForLocalItem($filename);
$prop = Get-TfsItemProperty -Item $tfsPath -Server $tfsServer -Workspace $script:tfsws;
$tfsws.Get(@($tfsPath), [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionSpec]::Parse($prop.VersionLatest,     $script:tfsws.OwnerName)[0], [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.RecursionType]::Full, [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.GetOptions]::None)
```

Comment: Im using your code here, which works really well, however, I cant find a way to execute this code and have it update its work through the powershell command prompt... in other words, it just works silently behind the scenes...